# why the inference time of SSD on smaller image is longer than bigger image while using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow-ssd

I found the **inference time of SSD on smaller image is longer than bigger image while using GPU** and don't know why.

I'm learning the code of SSD_tensorflow on https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow, I changed the feat_shapes in net code so that I can test images of different sizes, when I recorded the inference time of the vgg_ssd300, I found a curious phenomenon:

**the inference time of image(720*1280) is shorter than the image(300*760)**

I'm very confused about it so I did some tests, and I found:

1. when the length-width ratio is close to 1:2, the inference time will be extremely large, even larger than the image which has bigger size but the length-width ratio is 1:1

   my test result is:

   t(720, 1280, 3) < t(306, 763, 3)

   t(720, 1280, 3) < t(308, 665, 3)

   t(720, 1280, 3) < t(307, 1144, 3)

   t(720, 1280, 3) < t(302, 739, 3)
2. this only happened on GPU. On CPU, whatever the length-width ratio is, the time is always longer when the image size is larger.

Has anyone found this problem?

Comment: This seems like badly optimized GPU code. GPU programming has all sorts of pitfalls, they may have hit one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll look for solution from this point of view. By the way, the code I used is exactly the code in github SSD_tensorflow except the feat_shape. Did you know any pitfalls this code have?